# Esclarecimento vs Explicação'

Tags: português-europeu, vocabulário

Can any natives out there explain/clarify  the difference between 'esclarecimento' and 'explicação' (this is not an ironic joke).

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @ThamirysBrunello. In English, I do understand what the difference between these two concepts is. Let me word my question in a little more detail.
If: 
- Portuguese for explanation is 'explicação'
- Portuguese for clarification is 'clarificação'

Where does 'exclarecimento' fit in to the mix? 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Clarification consists of providing more information on a given subject, to resolve or resolve any doubts, comments, on the subject in question. Explanation consists of presenting general or detailed information on a subject. The difference between clarification and explanation is that when you explain something, you present information about the chosen subject, and doubts arise about the subject, you clarify it, it gives you the possibility of delving into the subject in order to resolve or discuss it, that is, , in the explanation you inform, in the clarification you enter the subject presenting more information.

Comment: Bem vinda ao site, Thamirys, e obrigado pela contribuição. A pessoa que colocou a questão talvez não domine o português, dado que fez a pergunta em inglês - se você puder, seria uma boa ideia adicionar na tua resposta uma versão em inglês dela. Se você não puder, avise aqui, e talvez algum dos outros usuários se voluntarie para traduzir.